# 2nd order matrix derivative in OLS derivation

Tags: calculus, regression, matrix-calculus, machine-learning

I am trying to derive the ordinary least squares formula using matrices.

The residual sum of squares is given by $(y - X\beta)(y - X\beta)^T$. I expanded this out to $yy^T - 2y\beta^Tx^T + x\beta\beta^Tx^T$. Now I want to take the derivative of this expression with respect to $\beta$.

I know how to take the derivative of the first two terms, but how do I take the derivative of the $x\beta\beta^Tx^T$ term? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your'e slightly wrong, note that
\begin{align}
S(\beta) &= (y-X\beta)'(y-X\beta)\\
         &=y'y + \beta'X'X\beta - 2\beta X'y,
\end{align}
now, note that $X'X=A$ is a square matrix of size order $p+1$, thus $\beta' X'X\beta = \beta' A \beta$ is quadratic form, hence 
$$
\beta' A \beta = \sum_j\sum_i \beta_j \beta_ia_{ij} = \sum\beta_j^2a_{jj} + 2\sum_{i < j}\beta_i \beta_j a_{ij},
$$
taking derivative w.r.t. $\beta$ you'll have that 
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} (\beta' A \beta) = 2\sum_j \beta_j a_{jj} + 2 \sum_{i < j} \beta_ja_{ij} = 2A\beta,
$$
i.e.,
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial \beta} (\beta' X'X \beta) = 2X'X\beta. 
$$

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach is to take the derivative first, and expand afterwards.

That way you only have to differentiate a single term.

Let $w=(X\beta-y)$, then jot down the function, the differential and the gradient 
$$\eqalign{
 S &= w:w \cr
dS &= 2w:dw = 2w:X\,d\beta = 2X^Tw:d\beta \cr
\frac{\partial S}{\partial\beta} &= 2X^Tw = 2X^T(X\beta-y) \cr
}$$
where a colon represents the trace/Frobenius product, i.e. $\,A:B={\rm tr}(A^TB)$